# Device is incorrectly detected as 32bit by Android?

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit, abi, armv8

Huawei Honor 9S device (with Android 10) has reportedly 64bit CPU (Mediatek MT6762R Helio P22 which supports armv8l), but `Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS` is empty (`String[0]`) and no armv8 shared libs are extracted from AAB by Android, but armv7a instead.

Is it misdetected? Is it Android or Huawei issue? Even if there is [a better] way to detect ABI correctly how to make Android extract the right shared libs?

Comment: I've the same issue with Ulefone Note 8P (Android 10). It's Mediatek MT6737, Cortex-A53 supports 64 bit. `But Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS` is empty. For me it's also not clear who is responsible and how to fix it. If possible at all.

Comment: _"Mediatek MT6762R Helio P22 which supports armv8l"_ Based on the limited information I can find about armv8l it seems that it is 32-bit ARMv8. So in that case it seems to correct for the 32-bit libraries (armv7a) to be used.

Comment: @Michael when I lookup the chips here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MediaTek_processors they all seem to use Cortex-A53, which is 64 bit capable.
I don't know where the "armv8l" came from, but to my knowledge armv7 is 32 bit and armv8 64 bit. The "l" in the end seems to be for little endian.

Comment: Yeah, i did not notice "l" but it can make a difference..

Comment: experiencing the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550217/apk-installation-fails-with-nativehelper-failure-copying-native-libraries-erro