# APK installation fails with NativeHelper: Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-113]

Tags: android, arm64, abi, armv7, armv8

APK installation fails on Mediatek processors that by documentation support `arm64-v8a`.
On other devices with Snapdragon or Exynos installation finishes successfully.

So far we found two devices with following chips:

- Mediatek MT6762 Helio P22 (12 nm)
- Mediatek MT6761 Helio A22 (12 nm)

It must support `arm64-v8a` architecture but installation fails.

When we compile application with `armeabi-v7a` installation is successful.

If someone encountered similar problem, is there any ways to solve this or is it chip limitation?

Similar: [Device is incorrectly detected as 32bit by Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769808/device-is-incorrectly-detected-as-32bit-by-android)

Comment: Probably a 64-bit device with a 32-bit OS.

Comment: that was correct. Samsung device we have had was 64bit hardware but 32bit firmware